# iOS SwiftUI ScrollView in NavigationStack: Scroll To Top Doesn't Finish Expanding Navigation Title, If Animated

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack, swiftui-scrollview, scrollviewreader

I'm needing to implement a scroll-to-top button for a ScrollView living in a NavigationStack, but when I call proxy.scrollTo() (with proxy being the ScrollViewProxy provided by ScrollViewReader), the jump to the top doesn't complete the expansion of the navigation title if it's called in a withAnimation{} block. If proxy.scrollTo() is not in a withAnimation{} block, the jump to top completes as expected. I'm providing simplified code that demonstrates the issue. (*This is not my project. Just a demo of the issue I'm seeing.)

I'm seeing the behavior with XCode 15.2 testing on iOS 16.4, 17.0.1, and 17.2. Device, simulator, and preview.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack() {
            LazyVNavView()
                .navigationTitle("THE LAZYVNAV")
        }
    }
}

struct LazyVNavView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { rowIndex in
                        Text("Row " + String(rowIndex))
                            .id(rowIndex)
                    }
                    
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button("To Top: Animation") {
                            withAnimation{
                                proxy.scrollTo(0)
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        Button("To Top: No Animation") {
                            proxy.scrollTo(0)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

The issue persists if I:
- designate an anchor for scrollTo()
- use a VStack instead of LazyVStack
- put the to-top button on an overlay
- put the button and list in a ZStack
- dispatch the scrollTo() call to the main thread
- move ScrollViewReader inside ScrollView
- implement a NavigationPath.

The code shown is the simplest way I could come up with to demonstrate the issue. Images of the results after jumping with and without animation attached.

withAnimation { proxy.scrollTo(0) } *using animation - yuck
[image]

proxy.scrollTo(0) *no animation - succeeds

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to produce this, even with all display modes. NavigationTitle always becomes `.inline` when tapping to scroll with or without animation.

Comment: Could not replicate your issue either, all works well for me in my tests. On MacOS 14.3, using Xcode 15.2, tested on real ios 17 devices (not Previews) and macCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: I neglected to mention that I'm working with iOS. Currently seeing the behavior with XCode 15.2 testing on iOS 16.4, 17.0.1, and 17.2. Device, simulator, and preview.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate your issue and found a way to mitigate it. This is likely a bug and you should file a bug report to Apple I think. The way I "solved it" was to use the animation and then move to scroll view to zero with a delay without the animation:

```
Button("To Top: Animation") {
     withAnimation{
         proxy.scrollTo(0)
     }
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
          proxy.scrollTo(0)
     }
}
```

This way the animation completes and it is almost unnoticeable that the last part completes without the animation.